# network issue ubuntu 8.04 in vmware esx

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vmware-esx

ok, this is really pissing me off

I have one ubuntu 8.04 instance running on vmware (esx) which decided after a reboot to stop resolving dns requests, I also cant connect to it using ssh although I can ping the server and its really that server (when I shutdown the server the ping also stops)

stuff I tried:
- reboot again :)
- nslookup - serverip
- setting networking to dhcp
- offering some cute kittens to lucifer
- removing the virtual nic and adding another (to get a different mac)
- migrating the instance to another esx host
- drinking 20 cups of espresso
- stopped all services
- running dnsmasq on another server and connecting to that dns
- tcpdumping 
- disabling ip6

symptoms:

- cant resolve anything
- nslookup just says "no servers found..." although I can ping the servers
- traceroute to gateway doesnt work (even with traceroute -4 -n gatewayip)
- collegues laughing at me

any thoughts

---

solved it:

a collegue told me to upgrade/reinstall the vmware tools, I did and it solved my issue after rebooting

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your /etc/nsswitch.conf? This file specifies configuration values for some functions in the C Library and any monkey business in here can cause DNS resolution problems.

The default /etc/nsswitch.conf on my 8.04 hosts looks like this:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

Comment: thx, we allready checked this